# Bluemix Mobile First Container Preview Error

Tags: service, containers, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst

I created with IBM Bluemix a MYSQL-Service, a Container(mobilefirst) and a containerbridge.
In the mobile first container I deployed my application and adapter.
When i open the app-preview I get the following error:
[image]

How can i solve this problem?. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How did you open the preview? Did you click a button or did you manually enter it?

There is no preview servlet available when using the console outside of the development environment (Eclipse). This explains the 404.

Comment: I clicked the preview Button in the Worklight Console.
I have an other problem, i get the following error: 
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found in Worklight platform.
Do you know how to solve this one?